# Possible to share code without .zip files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm building something simple and am not interested in using zip files and serverless and/or other frameworks -- I'm using the aws console only.

Can I share my functions/libraries between lambda functions in a simpler way?

For instance, I created a file called 'email_functions.py', put some code in there, then did a 'import email_functions' in my lambda function file, then use the code with 'email_functions.my_cool_function()'.

If not, I was thinking of just using a single lambda function for my limited needs, and one of the parameters would just be a 'command' -- like 'add_user' or 'verify_email' etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can share libs between lambda, using Lambda Layers:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: Those are still zip files though.